# How to add series to an empty chart without breaking the plot border in highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying to  add a series to an empty chart in high charts, this chart will sometimes have a plot border but when adding a series to a chart with a plot border, the plot border doesn't seem to adjust  to meet the new plot area.

Here is a jsfiddle with the problem
http://jsfiddle.net/Lzpztwf7/1/

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#fff',
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            plotBorderColor: '#777',
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
});

chart.addSeries({"name":"series 1","data": [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]});
```

And here is a jsfiddle of how it should look, with the series defined in the options:
http://jsfiddle.net/ebj9jn6w/

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#fff',
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            plotBorderColor: '#777',
    },
   xAxis: {
           categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
        },
        series: [{"name":"series 1","data": [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]}]
    });
```

It's not possible for me to just add the series in at the start because the users add the data in, and can remove it and add new data, as well as change various options on the chart either before or after adding data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding an empty series in the initial options and the use the `series.update` from the API to update

[**HIGHCHARTS DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/mgvgfrww/)

```
var chart = Highcharts.chart('container', {
    chart: {
            renderTo: 'container',
            borderWidth: 1,
            borderColor: '#fff',
            plotBorderWidth: 1,
            plotBorderColor: '#777',
    },

    xAxis: {
        categories: ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']
    },
    series: [{}]
});

chart.series[0].update({name: "Your series", data: [29.9, 71.5, 106.4, 129.2, 144.0, 176.0, 135.6, 148.5, 216.4, 194.1, 95.6, 54.4]})
```

Comment: Thanks this worked to fix the issue, or at least this particular part of the issue with adding a series, it revealed more issues which is the plot border just isn't resizing at all, to any change, and they can change a lot that would require the plot border to resize.

Here is a quick jsfiddle to show the issue with adding an extra yAxis 

http://jsfiddle.net/ebj9jn6w/1/


But they can also change the height and width etc which also breaks in the same way.


Any idea how to get the plot border to redraw its self?

Comment: You are welcome. I will take a look at the other problem after 4 hours.

Comment: @JamesSalt Please check this fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/h0pmsp5x/ if this is what you are expecting.